# Is it possible to lock or override game object scale property coordinates in inspector window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I want to know if it is possible to lock or override the X and Y coordinates of the scale property in the inspector window so that changing one coordinate immediately changes the other and scrubbing through one coordinate changes the value of the other. If yes, how can it be done?

Comment: Yes it is possible, look into executeInEditMode.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code and be more specific in your need?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues sorry, I don't have any code to show for this, because I'm not sure how it could be done. Here are some more details. Every game object has a transform property shown in the inspector window. The scale property coordinate fields can be filled in one by one. I want to lock/synchronize/override the  X and Y coordinates for the scale so that they are always the same. i.e if I change X scale coordinate to 3, Y also changes to 3 and also if I mouse scrub to increase value of one, the same value occurs for the other.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues preferably a button to turn this functionality on/off would be a plus

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Eddge, the `ExecuteInEditMode` attribute is a way to make it posible (check [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) for more info).

Here is a proof-of-concept (naive) implementation that locks up `x` and `y` scales.

**Edit**: To test it, create a new component with this code an attatch it to the object you want to apply. Then, set/unset the field `isLocked` to control the behavior.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class AspectRatioLock : MonoBehaviour
{
  public bool isLocked;
  Vector3 prevScale;

  void Start()
  {
    prevScale = transform.localScale;
  }

  void Update()
  {
    var scale = transform.localScale;
    if (isLocked && scale.x != prevScale.x)
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale.x, scale.y * scale.x / prevScale.x, scale.z);
    else if (isLocked && scale.y != prevScale.y)
      transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale.x * scale.y / prevScale.y, scale.y, scale.z);
    prevScale = transform.localScale;
  }
}
```

Actually there is an `AspectRatioFitter` component [pre-buit in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html), but it works with `RectTransform`, so it's suitable for UI elements.

Comment: I've been trying to work with your proof-of-concept to get lock the scales but haven't made much progress. What I originally had in mind was a way to override the scales so that stuff like `[executeInEditMode]` and and `Update` method wouldn't be needed. I also thought `AspectRatioFitter` is for UI elements, I want to do this on game objects.

Comment: What do you mean? I tested the code and the scales are indeed locked with this code. Also, why wouldn't you want `ExexuteInEditMode` for this? This is just what this attribute was made for. It is a simple class, with a short Update method, and even if this would cause overhead (it won't) it would do so in Editor, not in game... Anyway, other way to do this could be doing the same but with a custom Editor.

Comment: When I tested it, it didn't work, the scale coordinates were unchanged - I had to enter them one by one. I thought there was a way to override the original scale property so that it could update without using `[executeInEditMode]` and `Update`.  Anyway, I guess I'd prefer the custom editor approach

Comment: Did you set the isLocked field to true?

Comment: Yes. I set it to true. I think I've just found the issue with the code you provided. I was using values less than 1. It doesn't work for values less than 1. After entering a value less than 1 to one coordinate it starts adding the difference to the other coordinate.

Comment: As I said in the answer, this is a proof of concept implementation, you could adjust it to cover the special cases. The code as is break for scales <=0, bit I'm pretty sure it works for scales between 0 and 1

Comment: The reason I thought the scale coordinate locking wasn't working in the first place was because I tested it with values between 0 and 1. These values are not working. I understand it's a proof of concept but I don't think scale values between 0 and 1 fall under a special use case.

Comment: I retested the code and I am pretty sure it works with any scales lower than 1 (including negative scales). The only value it crashes is 0 (floaring point exception by dividing by zero), as expected. And this is what I mean when I say "special cases". If it is not working in your project, it may have a different reason. If you post more info on your error, environment and object hierarchy, I may be able to help you :)

Comment: @TenOutOfTen so, any update on this? Did you have success with this approach after all?